# Factory can only process 10 orders per day. How to push dates ahead after 10 orders?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm working in an Excel file that simply has two columns: "Order Number" and "Date."

If there are more than 10 orders for a given day, the orders over 10 need to "spill" to the next work day. Of course there's already orders for that next work day. So moving the original date to the next work day may make *that* day's orders go over 10. It's kind of a recursive problem.

I started in Power Query and used an Index column that starts at 0 and resets to 0 for each group of 10 Order Numbers. Then added a custom column with **Date.Add([Date],[Index])**. Then I tried Mod() and some other fails.

The answer seems to need to know if a row is over 10 orders *and* know the already adjusted date (if being over 10 already happened earlier.)

Again, it feels recursive.

I've had some real wins in Power Query and this is my first real-world head-scratcher.

Data:

```
Order Number   Date
1            1/1/2020
2            1/1/2020
3            1/1/2020
...
10           1/1/2020
11           1/1/2020
12           1/1/2020
13           1/2/1020
14           1/2/2020
```

---

Expected Output:

```
Order Number   Date
1            1/1/2020
2            1/1/2020
3            1/1/2020
...
10           1/1/2020
11           1/2/2020
12           1/2/2020
13           1/2/1020
14           1/2/2020
...
20           1/2/2020
21           1/3/2020
22           1/3/2020
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how the data should look, with the original column and the expected one?

Comment: @Jonee - Samples added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I'm not sure how well the code below will scale (say if you have millions of rows), but you can try the code and see if it gives you expected output. (I think it should, but you didn't give an example of your table and what it should look like, so I can't be sure.)
- You didn't define "working day". Can we unconditionally assume Monday-Friday, or are there public holidays (which may fall inclusively between Monday and Friday) which should be excluded?
- Code below assumes the definition of the next working day is whatever the next available order date is (in the table itself). However, using this definition introduces the following issues:

  - Is it possible that the last order date (present in the table) will have more than 10 orders?
  - If so, what should be done with orders that spill over beyond the last order date?
  - Your order dates must be sorted in ascending order (before you start looping over them).
- For now the code returns both the transformed table and any unused rows that have spilled over beyond the last available working day. (You can then choose to do whatever you want with them.)

---

I assume your table looks something like:

[image: Initial table]

and the code below:

```
let
    initialTable = 
        let
            listsOfDates = List.Transform({1..20}, each List.Dates(#date(2020, 1, 1), _, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))),
            combined = List.Combine(listsOfDates),
            dateColumn = Table.FromColumns({List.Sort(combined)}, type table [orderDate = date]),
            orderNumberColumn = Table.AddColumn(dateColumn, "orderNumber", each Text.NewGuid(), type text)
        in orderNumberColumn,
    grouped = Table.Group(initialTable, "orderDate", {"nested", each _, type table}),
    emptyTable = Table.FirstN(initialTable, 0),
    accumulated = List.Accumulate(
        List.Buffer(Table.ToRecords(grouped)),
        [
            spilledOver = emptyTable,
            result = emptyTable
        ],
        (state as record, row as record) =>
            let
                MAX_ROW_COUNT = 10,
                currentDate = row[orderDate],
                currentTable = Table.TransformColumns(state[spilledOver], {"orderDate", each currentDate, type date}) & row[nested],
                shouldSpillOver = Table.RowCount(currentTable) > MAX_ROW_COUNT,
                appended = state[result] & Table.FirstN(currentTable, MAX_ROW_COUNT),
                newState = if shouldSpillOver then 
                        [spilledOver = Table.Skip(currentTable, MAX_ROW_COUNT), result = appended]
                    else 
                        [spilledOver = emptyTable, result = appended]
            in newState
    ),
    result = accumulated[result]
in
    result
```

should give you a `record` which has two fields: `spilledOver` and `result`, wherein:

- `spilledOver` should be a table containing any rows that spilled over beyond the last available date (and are therefore "unassigned"). If there were no such rows (for the last available date), `spilledOver` should be an empty table.
- `result` should be a table wherein each order date should have no more than 10 orders. (You should be able to confirm this by grouping `result` by `"orderDate"` and aggregating by `Table.RowCount`, then checking if any are over 10.)

---

Obviously, you'll need to adjust the code for your own table's column names.

Comment: This is more than I could have ever hoped for. There's a lot to learn from this code. Thank you so much! I can't wait to be this good at Power Query (M language).

Comment: I'm stepping through your code now and it's really a class on how to approach a problem in M creatively. To answer your open questions: 1. ""working day" meant work days (Monday-Friday). There is a list of public holidays available in table or list form. 2. There is no end date restriction. The factory will produce 10 per day until all orders are completed. These are the things I'm trying to understand how to inject into your existing codebase.